# How include into the project Neodynamic references?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sdk, neodynamic

I want to use the neodynamic image draw SDK and I keep getting this error when I build. This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Web;    
using System.Web.UI;    
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;    
using Neodynamic.SDK.ImageDraw;    
using Neodynamic;    
using Neodynamic.SDK;    

   namespace demoImage

{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page    
    {         
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           Neodynamic.SDK.ImageElement imgElem = new Neodynamic.SDK.ImageElement();    
           imgElem.Source = Neodynamic.SDK.ImageSource.File;    
            imgElem.SourceFile = "http://www.domain.com/imageSample.jpg";    
           Neodynamic.SDK.TextElement txtElem = new Neodynamic.SDK.TextElement();    
            txtElem.Font.Name = "Arial";    
            txtElem.Font.Size = 36.0f;    
            txtElem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson;    
            txtElem.StrokeWidth = 4;    
            txtElem.StrokeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;    
            txtElem.Text = "Watermark";    
       }    
    }    
}
```

I am getting an error in the

```
Neodynamic.SDK.ImageElement imgElem = new Neodynamic.SDK.ImageElement()
```

line.

Comment: what do you mean by none work?

Comment: @MPatel-i am new this concept is,were to start i dont know also.,i downloaded dll file also and add reference also.,